# Emulator Process Termination Error: Unable to Read .ini File in Android AVD

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

Good day StackOverflow community, I'm currently encountering an issue with the Android Studio emulator, as it fails to run and displays the following error message: `The emulator process for AVD Pixel_6_API_33 has terminated.` The log information is provided below:

```
PS C:\Users\amith\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator> .\emulator -avd Pixel_6_API_33
INFO    | Android emulator version 32.1.13.0 (build_id 10086546) (CL:N/A)
INFO    | Found systemPath C:\Users\amith\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-33\google_apis\x86_64\
INFO    | Storing crashdata in: C:\Users\amith\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash.db, detection is enabled
INFO    | Duplicate loglines will be removed, if you wish to see each indiviudal line launch with the -log-nofilter flag.
INFO    | IPv4 server found: 103.153.93.230
WARNING | Failed to process .ini file C:\Users\amith\.android\avd\Pixel_6_API_33.avd\quickbootChoice.ini for reading.
INFO    | Crash reports will be automatically uploaded to: https://clients2.google.com/cr/report
INFO    | Report ab087648-bfac-463e-9eea-a5cf07f74b1a is available remotely as: 6934cf7ffd17a45c, deleting.
INFO    | added library vulkan-1.dll
PS C:\Users\amith\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator>
```

the warning error is `Failed to process .ini file C:\Users\amith\.android\avd\Pixel_6_API_33.avd\quickbootChoice.ini for reading.`
but there is no file named `quickbootChoice.ini`:
[image: noQuickBootChoiceIniFileImgenter code here]

I tried following thing:

1. reinstalled Android studio
2. Created new AVD(with different specification)
3. Installed HyperV
4. checked all necessary checkbox sdk manager

I have been working with Android Studio for a while, and I have never encountered this issue before. I would greatly appreciate any help and assistance from the Stack Overflow community. Thank you.

Comment: Encountered same problem lately with emulator in Visual Studio Comuunity 2022. What OS are you working with? Is it Windows 11 Home maybe?

Comment: @ArturWyszomirski Yes WIndow 11, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76595583/why-i-cant-use-api-level-from-29-to-34-avd-in-android-studio this helped me | change graphics to software GLES 2.0

Comment: Yes, similar solution in VS. Need to change hw.gpu.mode from 'auto' to 'angle' in emulated device properties.

Answer (score 0):

1, Disable anti virus ( restart android studio and run emulator) not working try 2nd method.

2, still error delete avd device reinstall avd ( still Disable anti virus).

3, check your system storage had enough.

4, check sdk path restricted or not.

Comment: @ Prasanth John I created a new AVD, which is a Pixel 4 emulator running on API level 26 (Oreo), and it is functioning properly. However, I'm experiencing issues with the AVD running on API level 33 (Tiramisu); it is not working at all and displays the error mentioned earlier.