# Why I cant use API level from 29 to 34 AVD in android studio

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, android-api-levels

I can run my Android app on AVDs with API levels below 29, but I cannot run my app on API levels 29 and above (e.g. Q, S, R, Tirasumi etc.).Error:
[image]

logs:

```
2023-07-01 21:50:20,520 [2416819]   INFO - #c.i.c.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving appEditorColorsManagerImpl took 30 ms, TodoConfiguration took 37 ms
2023-07-01 21:50:26,231 [2422530]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 Pro API 33 - C:\Users\amith\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Pixel_6_Pro_API_33 -qt-hide-window -grpc-use-token -idle-grpc-timeout 300
2023-07-01 21:50:26,276 [2422575]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 Pro API 33 - Android emulator version 32.1.14.0 (build_id 10330179) (CL:N/A)
2023-07-01 21:50:26,276 [2422575]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 Pro API 33 - Found systemPath C:\Users\amith\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-33\google_apis\x86_64\
2023-07-01 21:50:28,051 [2424350]   WARN - Emulator: Pixel 6 Pro API 33 - Failed to process .ini file C:\Users\amith\.android\avd\Pixel_6_Pro_API_33.avd\quickbootChoice.ini for reading.
2023-07-01 21:50:32,386 [2428685]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 Pro API 33 - Process finished with exit code 1073741845
2023-07-01 21:50:32,386 [2428685] SEVERE - Emulator: Pixel 6 Pro API 33 - Emulator terminated with exit code 1073741845
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Emulator issues in new versions - The emulator process has terminated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67346232/android-emulator-issues-in-new-versions-the-emulator-process-has-terminated)

Comment: thanks for replying,No it doesnt answer my question,In my case API level below 29 works well but i cant even open AVD above 29 i wonder why ?

Comment: @C.F.G ive added log info on my question section

Comment: Wipe the data of your device and try starting it again.

Comment: Generally, APIs above 25 are very heavy and needs more RAM and Hard Disk speed. My Machin has 8G of RAM and runs APIs+26 very hardly.

Comment: @C.F.G I tried that. I've literally tried almost everything on YouTube and Stack Overflow, but I couldn't find a solution.

Comment: Have you tried using AVDs with API levels above 28, starting from Q @C.F.G

Comment: yes, I've used API 31 and 32 but as I said they slow down my computer terribly. In the linked post there are different answers, try them.

Comment: thanks, changing graphics to software GLES 2.0 worked for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

1. Create new AVD
2. select the API level
   [image]
3. click on Show Advanced settings
   [image]
4. change graphics to software GLES 2.0 in emulated performance section
   [image]